# Как узнать что элемент страницы попал в поле зрения пользователя

Tags: jquery

В самом низу страницы имеется баннер. При открытии страницы его не видно, чтобы его увидеть требуется прокрутить страницу.
Можно ли определить, что страница была прокручена до уровня видимости баннера и послать сигнал PHP-скрипту (т.е. засчитать просмотр баннера)?

Comment: добавить обработчик scroll: $(window).scroll(function(){ /* тут проверить видимость */ }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="banner" 
     style="margin-top:1000px; height: 30px; width:100px; background-color: red;" />
```

---

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function isVisible(tag) {
    var t = $(tag);
    var w = $(window);
    var wt = w.scrollTop();
    var tt = t.offset().top;
    var tb = tt + t.height();
    return ((tb <= wt + w.height()) && (tt >= wt));
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var b = $("#banner");
        if (!b.prop("shown") && isVisible(b)) {
            b.prop("shown", true);
            alert("послать сигнал");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Как бы его заставить посылать сигнал только один раз? срабатывает повторно при малейшей прокрутке страницы.

Comment: @Plush _"Как бы его заставить посылать сигнал только один раз?"_ -- если баннер был показан и был послан сигнал, то можно установить флаг/атрибут и при следующей прокрутке проверять этот флаг.

Comment: @Plush добавил в ответ.

Comment: Еще заметил, что когда баннер попал в поле зрения и сигнал послан, то при обновлении страницы (браузер оставит скролл на том же месте что и до обновления страницы, то есть баннер попадает в поле зрения автоматом) сигнал не посылается, разве что пользователь прокрутит страницу хотя бы на `1px`. Можно как-то послать сигнал в этом случае? `$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);` - прокрутить получилось, но вызвать `$(window).scroll()` чтобы послать сигнал не получается.

Comment: @Plush _"при обновлении страницы (браузер оставит скролл на том же месте что и до обновления страницы, то есть баннер попадает в поле зрения автоматом"_ -- надо при загрузке страницы проверить `isVisible`. для этого проверку надо добавить в `$(function() {    });` сразу после `{`

Comment: Получилось. Скажите, если я вас правильно понял в посте выше, то у меня должно получиться две проверки `isVisible` и, соответственно, две строки отправки сигнала (в нашем случае `alert("послать сигнал");`) ? т.е. одной строкой отправить сигнал никак не получиться.

Comment: @Plush _"меня должно получиться две проверки isVisible"_ -- можно проверку вынести в отдельную функцию и вызывать ее после загрузки и при скроле. добавил новый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если проверять надо после загрузки страницы и во время скролла, то так:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function isVisible(tag) {
    var t = $(tag);
    var w = $(window);
    var wt = w.scrollTop();
    var tt = t.offset().top;
    var tb = tt + t.height();
    return ((tb <= wt + w.height()) && (tt >= wt));
}

function signal() {
  var b = $("#banner");
  if (!b.prop("shown") && isVisible(b)) {
    b.prop("shown", true);
    alert("послать сигнал");
  }
}

$(function () {
    signal();
    $(window).scroll(signal);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Пытаюсь еще добавить проверку `b.find("img").load(function() {` сразу после ` var b = $("#banner");` чтобы проверить что баннер загрузился, но сигнал посылается только при перезагрузке страницы, при скроллинге ничего.. У меня внутри контейнера `div#banner` есть текст и картинка-баннер.

Comment: @Plush _"Пытаюсь еще добавить проверку b.find("img").load(...)"_  -- может не вызываться, т.к. рис. к этому моменту уже загружен. проверить можно так `if(myImg.complete) { ... }`