# Как реализовать логически данную задачу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть левый сайдбар, который постоянно фиксировано идет за страницей. Там пункты меню, отзывы, сертификаты и.т.д. При клике на нем идет скролл на саму секцию.
Можно ли сделать так, что когда проходишь мимо секции, менялись стили для пунктов из левого сайдбара?

Comment: если кликаете и происходит скролл, то решите в обратную сторону при скролле проверьте положения и активируйте меню

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать что элемент страницы попал в поле зрения пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484601/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f)

Comment: Дайте в вопросе ваш кусок кода.щ

Comment: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/