# Вертикальный скролл текста

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят, пытаюсь реализовать скролл текста с фиксацией необходимого по центру. После скрола один текст плавно уходит верх и появляется новый (текстов будет куча). Дайте плз направление, название, пример. Заранее спасибо. [image: Пример]

Comment: Т.е. анимация? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484601/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F

Comment: Да, с анимацией движения. Где при скроле один текст заменяется другим

Answer (score 2):

Используйте это как базу для создания нужной вам анимации:

```js
var isScrolling = false;
 
    window.addEventListener("scroll", throttleScroll, false);
 
    function throttleScroll(e) {
      if (isScrolling == false) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          scrolling(e);
          isScrolling = false;
        });
      }
      isScrolling = true;
    }
 
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", scrolling, false);
 
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#mainContent ol li");
    var firstBox = document.querySelector("#firstBox");
    var secondBox = document.querySelector("#secondBox");
 
    function scrolling(e) {
 
      if (isPartiallyVisible(firstBox)) {
        firstBox.classList.add("active");
 
        document.body.classList.add("colorOne");
        document.body.classList.remove("colorTwo");
      } else {
        document.body.classList.remove("colorOne");
        document.body.classList.remove("colorTwo");
      }
 
      if (isFullyVisible(secondBox)) {
        secondBox.classList.add("active");
 
        document.body.classList.add("colorTwo");
        document.body.classList.remove("colorOne");
      }
 
      for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        var listItem = listItems[i];
 
        if (isPartiallyVisible(listItem)) {
          listItem.classList.add("active");
        } else {
          listItem.classList.remove("active");
        }
      }
    }
 
    function isPartiallyVisible(el) {
      var elementBoundary = el.getBoundingClientRect();
 
      var top = elementBoundary.top;
      var bottom = elementBoundary.bottom;
      var height = elementBoundary.height;
 
      return ((top + height >= 0) && (height + window.innerHeight >= bottom));
    }
 
    function isFullyVisible(el) {
      var elementBoundary = el.getBoundingClientRect();
 
      var top = elementBoundary.top;
      var bottom = elementBoundary.bottom;
 
      return ((top >= 0) && (bottom <= window.innerHeight));
    }
```

```css
 body {
      background-color: #FDE74C;
      transition: all 1s ease-in;
      padding: 50px;
      color: #111;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      line-height: 32px;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
 
    h1 {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
 
    .colorOne {
      background-color: #9BC53D;
      color: #000;
    }
 
    .colorTwo {
      background-color: #FFF;
      color: #000;
    }
 
    #mainContent {
      width: 420px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
 
    #mainContent p {
      padding: 20px;
    }
 
    #mainContent #firstBox {
      font-weight: bold;
      transform: translate3d(-30px, 0, 0);
      transition: all .5s ease-out;
      opacity: 0;
    }
 
    #mainContent #firstBox.active {
      background-color: #333;
      color: #FFF;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
 
    #mainContent #secondBox {
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
      opacity: 0;
    }
 
    #mainContent #secondBox.active {
      background-color: #1581AF;
      color: #FFF;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
 
    #mainContent ol li {
      padding-left: 7px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      transform: translate3d(20px, 0, 0);
      opacity: 0;
    }
 
    #mainContent ol li.active {
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Change Color on Scroll</title>
 
</head>
 
<body>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur quis massa a arcu efficitur suscipit vehicula et risus.</p>
    <ol id="myList">
      <li>Nam sagittis est non enim ultrices elementum. </li>
      <li>Sed id ligula sed mi tempor ornare.</li>
      <li>Aenean feugiat risus eget sagittis volutpat. Proin quis orci a metus lacinia auctor eget id nisi.</li>
      <li>Donec pulvinar nunc feugiat semper consequat.</li>
      <li>Etiam cursus justo eget libero gravida, nec faucibus mauris posuere.</li>
      <li>In nec sem id libero egestas cursus vel a urna.</li>
      <li>Fusce pulvinar arcu eu lobortis egestas. Maecenas eleifend felis ut urna consectetur, et pellentesque mi molestie.</li>
      <li>Aliquam ut felis venenatis, dapibus ante non, gravida nulla.</li>
      <li>Donec consectetur quam in urna commodo, sed aliquet metus vehicula.</li>
      <li>Mauris eget est sit amet felis eleifend sagittis non id nulla.</li>
    </ol>
    <p id="firstBox">Phasellus tortor nisl, dapibus at posuere sed, tempor in massa. Pellentesque eu sodales orci, finibus congue libero. Mauris molestie bibendum posuere.</p>
    <p>Nunc blandit varius sapien quis ultrices. Vestibulum et consequat augue. Pellentesque et maximus nisl, sit amet dictum ante.</p>
    <p id="secondBox">Nullam magna augue, consequat eu augue ut, volutpat fringilla est. Ut commodo ac magna vulputate dictum.</p>
  </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```