# Scale Image CSS, JS

Tags: css, jquery

**Задача:** Выполнить scale используя animate().

Это необходимо выполнить, когда изображение попадает в поле зрения.

**Вопрос:** Как узнать, что объект находится в поле зрения?

P.s: изображений на странице несколько и эффект применяется для каждого.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484601/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, принцип будет понятен. В примере цепляемся за контейнер родителя и показываем все его содержимое. Немного переставив участки скрипта можно цепляться за каждый элемент на странице. Зависит от конкретных задач.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $(".container").each(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView($(this))) {
      $(this).find(".element").addClass("active");
    }
  });
});

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

```css
.space {
  height: 110vh;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.element.active {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="space"></div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="element"></span>
  <span class="element"></span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="element"></span>
</div>
```